# How to concatenate the date in datenum with the year in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date

I need to get the payment dates of a bond. The payments dates are quarterly. I have already set up the date in a cell. But I need to concatenate it with the particular year, which I am not sue how to.

EffectiveDate = datenum('15/05');

I need to concatenate it with the year like 2012.

What i Tried:

> > join(EffectiveDate,year(datenum('15/05/12'))
> >
> > EffectiveDate + year

Both didn't give me a correct answer.

How do i do it? Need some help on this. Thanks.

Comment: EffectiveDate = datenum(2012,05,15)?

Comment: not this way, i mean in code

Comment: I mean programmatically...

Comment: Well, if what @Divakar wrote was not code then I do not know how to help

Comment: Give the variables and their type, we cannot assume

Comment: What i meant by programmatically is that i am writing this in a loop. so the value cannot be hardcoded.

Comment: I gave an answer below, but just to be sure, what output are you expecting? String? serial? as you have'nt defined what it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all values are given as strings:

```
date = '15/05';
year = '2012';

fullDate = [date,'/',year]; %String concatenation
```

now you can convert to serial form using `datenum`:

```
sDate = datenum(fullDate,'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Hope this is what you asked for